# Custom SeekBar: set min value

Tags: java, android

I need to set the seekbar values from -10 to 10. The default SeekBar class do not allow to set a minimum value but only max. How can i set also a minimum value? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the minimum value.
What you can do is:

`seekBar.setMax(20);`

Then simply offset the value you get from the seekbar:

`int progress = seekBar.getProgress() - 10;`

Answer (score 0):

I use, but **you must set first the min**.

```
public class SeekBarMin extends SeekBar {

   private int min;

   public SeekBarMin(Context context) {
     super(context);
     min = 0;
   }

   public SeekBarMin(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
      super(context, attrs);
      min = 0;
   }

   public SeekBarMin(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
      min = 0;
   }

   public synchronized void setMin(int min) {
      this.min = min;
   }

   public synchronized int getProgress() {
      return super.getProgress() + min;
   }

   public synchronized void setMax(int max) {
      super.setMax(max - min);
   }

   public int getMax() {
     super.getMax() + min;
   }

   public int getMin() {
      return min;

   }

}
```